# twitter account/update_profile_image 422 error

Tags: twitter

I have to upload avatar through Twitter API 1.1, but I always get 422 error.
This is my code:

```
var path = "avatar.jpg";
var req = token.GetQueryWebRequest("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json", HttpMethod.POST);

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;  /// ????????????

req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
var image = "image=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(getImageBase64Encode(path, 700));
var encode = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(image);
req.ContentLength = encode.Length;
var steam = req.GetRequestStream();
steam.Write(encode, 0, encode.Length);
var resp = req.GetResponse();

// ----------------
private string getImageBase64Encode(string filePath, int maxSize)
{
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Файл не существует: {0}", filePath));
var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
if(file.Length > maxSize * 1024)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Файл слишком большой: {0}", filePath));

byte[] res = null;
try
{
    res = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Неудалось прочитать файл: {0}", filePath));
}
if (res == null)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Файл пуст или поврежден: {0}", filePath));
}

return Convert.ToBase64String(res);
}
```

GetQueryWebRequest - get Request with oAuth header

do not offer frameworks

PS> Sorry, my english so bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem:

```
var imageByte = GetImageByte(path, 800);

var type = Path.GetExtension(path).Trim('.').ToLower();
var filename = Path.GetFileName(path);

if (type == "jpg") type = "jpeg";

if (type != "jpeg" && type != "png" && type != "gif") throw new Exception("Неверный формат файла для загрузки на сервер");

const string boundary = "--0246824681357ACXZabcxyz";
req.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; type=\"image/{0}\"; start=\"<banner>\"; boundary=\"{1}\"", type, boundary);
req.KeepAlive = true;
var image = string.Format(
  "--{0}\r\n" +
  "Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"banner\"\r\n" +
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n" +
  "Content-ID: <image>\r\n" +
  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"banner\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n" +
  "Content-Location: image\r\n" +
  "\r\n", boundary, filename);
var encode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(image);
var steam = req.GetRequestStream();
steam.Write(encode, 0, encode.Length);

steam.Write(imageByte, 0, imageByte.Length);

encode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
steam.Write(encode, 0, encode.Length);

req.GetResponse();
```